Salesforce connect(External object) vs UI based Integration(Rest)
@All - We have to build preferably a page( can be hosted within Salesforce or outside) which should be capable to showing data from multiple outside systems(> 5 systems, one such system itself is aggregating data from multiple internal system) and which will act kind of dashboard showing 360 view of customer information.
This page should be visible to certain internal users(e.g. 1-2 internal profiles) but number of such users > 1000, who may be daily visiting this page multiple number of times.

About Outside systems: some are hosted within our company network and some are external services

idea is user clicks a button on Account or Contact in Salesforce and a page should open that shows data from multiple such sources on fly(without the need to store that data in Salesforce)
I'm thinking two solutions :

Using Salesforce connect, utilizing oData to pull the data from all these systems(all support Rest). But Negative is oData has limitation of around 20k callouts per hour (for oData2.0 and oData4.0)

instead of oData, i'm thinking of directly making rest call to all these externals services to get data and showing them on UI


I'm not able to think, if there are any particular benefit I'll get using oData(Salesforce connect which I can't get using direct restAPI based web service call.
So question is simple, in what situation oData will be useful in comparison of custom web service development apart from the obvious fact it can avoid custom development!
(In my case, we definitely need custom development as we've to build a dashboard kind of page showing data from multiple sources)
please note, latest data(all web services call outs to be made) needs to be shown as soon as page loads after clicking button on Account or Contact
